# How to transpose a 2d vector using modern c++?

Tags: c++

Say I have a matrix defined by:

```
vector<vector<T>> matrix;
```

For example, before transpose:

```
{{1, 2},
 {3, 4}}
```

After transpose:

```
{{1, 3},
 {2, 4}}
```

Naive for loop solution as requested:

```
    for(i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < colSize; ++j)
        {
            transposed[j][i]=original[i][j];
        }
    }
```

I am wondering what's the modern way in C++ to do a transpose on it?
A naive solution is to use two for loops which is not what I am looking for. I am considering using `for_each` and `std::transform`. Can someone please make some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by modern? For loops aren't exactly old and obsolete. :D

Comment: You should include your naive solution. It's trivial, but usually questions are received better (see Ron's comment) if they include an attempted solution.

Comment: @ron unfortunately, in a certain way it is ...

Comment: @DeiDei Presumably a one or two lines, using functions from `<algorithm>` and a few lambdas. That's what's called modern these days. :P

Comment: post-modern: dont transpose it, but just swap the indices when accesing elements ;)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes you are right I am trying to get rid of for loops because people say they are not as efficient as for_each or transform ie if you look at the translated code by compiler a for loop is much longer.

Comment: Also, my advice would be to not use nested vectors to represent rectangular (as opposed to jagged) matrices. `vector<T>` of size `W * H` is faster.

Comment: `std::for_each` is completely identical to a for loop. Sure it looks more impressive with 5 <algorithm> functions put together...

Comment: @Rockingchief If you are looking for efficiency, start by not storing your matrix in a vector of vector and use a flatten array, or use a dedicated library altogether.

Comment: @Holt I have a static matrix that is using flatten array. This one is for dynamic one where the user can insert delete row or columns. So I guess in the dynamic one I should use vector<vector<T>>?

Comment: @Rockingchief You can insert row or columns in a flatten matrix, it's not that much work, especially if you use row-major. If you really need to work with lots of matrix and their related operations, maybe you should switch to some mathematical library, this would save you from lots of trouble...

Comment: The "modern approach" is to pick a suitable data structure and a suitable algorithm.   The first step would be to not use a `vector<vector<T>>` - instead use a flat matrix (e.g. an MxN matrix would have `M*N` elements in either row-dominant or column-dominant order).   Why?   There are algorithms for efficiently transposing such a matrix in place.

Comment: Of course it is not always possible to transpose a vector of vectors, e.g. `{{1},{2,3,4},{5}}` What do you want to do with this case? Ignore it? Throw an exception? Try to correct it somehow? Any of the above is potentially feasible. There's no one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always it completely depends on your needs. The most simple solution I can imagine is to not modify the data at all. Instead you can provide a wrapper that swaps the indices for access. Without guarantee for completeness or correctness (rather guaranteed to be incomplete and likely to have typos, but I hope you get the idea):

```
template <typename T>
struct transposed_ref {
    T& t;
    transposed_ref(T& t) : t(t) {}
    T::value_type& get(int x,int y) { return T[y][x]; }
};                                         //  ^  ^ --- note: swapped indices
```

Comment: While the idea is good, it is not simple at all. You will likely not be able to use your structure where a matrix was expected because the type won't match, you'll need to implement tons of methods to have something useful... This is basically implementing another container.

Comment: @Holt I am aware of that, but I felt that I should turn my sloppy comment into an answer (eg to allow others to point out shortcomings ;).

Comment: @Holt If i had one specific use case I would maybe use something tailored for that, but I completely agree that implementing a full container for the general case is waste of time and simply copying would be better