# Creating a 3D vector. C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

Help me please.
I have a 3d vector. I need to make a new vector from this using existing internal indices. I hope the input and output information will be clear.

Input:

```
    a = {
        { {1,1,1,1}, {2,2,2,2}, {3,3,3,3}, {4,4,4,4}, {5,5,5,5}, {6,6,6,6} },
        { {10,10,10,10}, {20,20,20,20}, {30,30,30,30}, {40,40,40,40}, {50,50,50,50}, {60,60,60,60} },
        { {100,100,100,100}, {200,200,200,200}, {300,300,300,300}, {400,400,400,400}, {500,500,500,500}, {600,600,600,600} },
    };
```

Output:

```
    b = {
        {{ 1,1,1,1}, {10,10,10,10}, {100,100,100,100}},
        {{ 2,2,2,2}, {20,20,20,20}, {200,200,200,200}},
        {{ 3,3,3,3}, {30,30,30,30}, {300,300,300,300}},
        {{ 4,4,4,4}, {40,40,40,40}, {400,400,400,400}},
        {{ 5,5,5,5}, {50,50,50,50}, {500,500,500,500}},
        {{ 6,6,6,6}, {60,60,60,60}, {600,600,600,600}},
    }
```

I don't know how to iterate over indices in a 3D array to create a new 3D array (Output). I want to create a 3D vector from the columns (n-indices) of an existing 3D vector. I have a 3D vector ('Input'). I need to make a 3D vector out of this ('Output').

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void show3D_vector(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>& a);
void show2D_vector(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& a);
template<typename T> std::vector<std::vector<T>> SplitVector(const std::vector<T>& vec, size_t n);


int main()
{
    
        a = {
        { {1,1,1,1}, {2,2,2,2}, {3,3,3,3}, {4,4,4,4}, {5,5,5,5}, {6,6,6,6} },
        { {10,10,10,10}, {20,20,20,20}, {30,30,30,30}, {40,40,40,40}, {50,50,50,50}, {60,60,60,60} },
        { {100,100,100,100}, {200,200,200,200}, {300,300,300,300}, {400,400,400,400}, {500,500,500,500}, {600,600,600,600} },
    }; 


}


void show3D_vector(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>& a)
{
    for (double i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (double j = 0; j < a[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            for (double k = 0; k < a[i][j].size(); ++k)
                std::cout << a[i][j][k] << "  ";
            std::cout << endl;
        }
        std::cout << endl;
    }
}

void show2D_vector(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        for (auto it = a[i].begin(); it != a[i].end(); it++)
        {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }

        std::cout << endl << endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> SplitVector(const std::vector<T>& vec, size_t n)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> outVec;

    size_t length = vec.size() / n;
    size_t remain = vec.size() % n;

    size_t begin = 0;
    size_t end = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(n, vec.size()); ++i)
    {
        end += (remain > 0) ? (length + !!(remain--)) : length;
        outVec.push_back(std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + begin, vec.begin() + end));
        begin = end;
    }

    return outVec;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So in your example, `n` is 4 since there are 4 distinct set of columns in the vector?  So we are assuming that `n` is always evenly divisible by the size of the data in one row of the `a` vector?  So something like 20 values and `n` being equal to 6 can never occur?

Comment: Yes, I think I understood you correctly

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224485/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-a-vector-of-vectors-columnwise/74229054#74229054

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you have a 2D-Vector containing vectors which you want to transpose? So in essence the solution of your problem is independent of the fact that you are storing `std::vectors` in your `std::vector<std::vector<SOMETHING>>`. If yes, see if this SO question helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998284/how-to-transpose-a-2d-vector-using-modern-c

Comment: After taking a look at your example, it seems this is just an extension of converting a row-major array (or vector) to a column-major array (vector).  Is there a reason for `n` to even exist, if this is the case?

Comment: That's true, I converted the task to an extension of converting an array of strings (or vector) to an array of columns (vector). I got rid of n and successfully solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this matrix transpose more succinctly.

```
    for(const auto& a1 : a){
        b.resize(a1.size());
        auto b1 = b.begin();
        for(const auto& a2 : a1){
            b1->push_back(a2);
            b1++;
        }
    }
```

output is

```
{{1,1,1,1,},{10,10,10,10,},{100,100,100,100,},},
{{2,2,2,2,},{20,20,20,20,},{200,200,200,200,},},
{{3,3,3,3,},{30,30,30,30,},{300,300,300,300,},},
{{4,4,4,4,},{40,40,40,40,},{400,400,400,400,},},
{{5,5,5,5,},{50,50,50,50,},{500,500,500,500,},},
{{6,6,6,6,},{60,60,60,60,},{600,600,600,600,},},
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your input and output in the example you posted, it seems to be just a transpose of the data, where `n` would be irrelevant.

If this is the case, the following code does this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void show3D_vector(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>& a)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < a[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << "{";
            for (size_t k = 0; k < a[i][j].size(); ++k)
            {
                if (k > 0)
                    std::cout << ",";
                std::cout << a[i][j][k];
            }
            std::cout << "} ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> Transpose(const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>& vec)
{
    if (vec.empty())
        return {};

    // Construct the output vector
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> 
         outVect(vec[0].size(), 
         std::vector<std::vector<T>>(vec.size()));

    // transpose loop
    for (size_t row = 0; row < vec.size(); ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < vec[0].size(); ++col)
            outVect[col][row] = vec[row][col];
    }
    return outVect;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> a = 
    {
        { {1,1,1,1}, {2,2,2,2}, {3,3,3,3}, {4,4,4,4}, {5,5,5,5}, {6,6,6,6} },
        { {10,10,10,10}, {20,20,20,20}, {30,30,30,30}, {40,40,40,40}, {50,50,50,50}, {60,60,60,60} },
        { {100,100,100,100}, {200,200,200,200}, {300,300,300,300}, {400,400,400,400}, {500,500,500,500}, {600,600,600,600} },
    };

    auto b = Transpose(a);
    show3D_vector(b);
}
```

Output:

```
{1,1,1,1} {10,10,10,10} {100,100,100,100} 
{2,2,2,2} {20,20,20,20} {200,200,200,200} 
{3,3,3,3} {30,30,30,30} {300,300,300,300} 
{4,4,4,4} {40,40,40,40} {400,400,400,400} 
{5,5,5,5} {50,50,50,50} {500,500,500,500} 
{6,6,6,6} {60,60,60,60} {600,600,600,600}
```

The other issue is that your `show3d_vector` function uses an incorrect type for the `for` loop counter.  It should be `size_t`, not `double`.